# Is it possible to text a number and have it redirect to the app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm looking into building an iOS app (let's call it New App) that allows you to text a specific number and automatically redirect you to the app store and populate New App ready to download on your screen. Eliminating the need to go to the app store, search, wait, etc.. Is something like that possible?

Comment: Have you thought about using a QR code?  QRStuff even claims they [have a way to consolidate all of the different phone types into a single QR code](http://www.qrstuff.com/blog/2012/12/28/qr-codes-for-app-store-downloads).

Comment: why text a number? why not the link to the app

Comment: SO Community: The question is perfectly clear.  Find a different close reason, if you think it's off topic.

Comment: @meda lets say I have an app that I want you to download, right? However, you don't want to go search for it in the app store, you rather have it in your possession quicker. If I could designate, say, a 5 or 6 digit number, that when you text pulls the app from the app store ready to download and just prompts you to enter in your password this would be easier and what I am looking for. Make sesne?

Comment: Yes I understood that, but the digits is not clear to me, I think you will be better off sending url to the app store like everyone does

Comment: I guess I'm just visualizing two people interacting and person A is telling person B about an app that is on his phone. Neither of these people are the creators of the app, just users. Person A wants Person B to try it, but person B is lazy and doesn't want to go search for it in the app store. So person A says, "Just text 55532" and the app will be download on your phone. I'm wondering if this is possible. So people can shortcut to the app.

Answer (score 0):

you could rollout your own hyperlink shortener. like other platforms have. and a custom URL handler in iOS.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening

and

http://wki.pe/URL_shortening